# Mysql query GROUP by and ORDER by

Tags: mysql

I have table called **msg** where i store all messages.
I want to select all rows with unique  **User** but only those with MAX **Id** field.

Comment: SELECT * FROM msg WHERE  MAX_Id IS NOT NULL GROUP BY User

Comment: post your table schema and sample of data. expected result and/or sqlfiddle would be very helpful

Comment: its not MAX_Id .... i want to select rows with unique field User but with max Id field

Comment: SO is **not a free coding service** What have to bothered to try for yourself

Comment: i want advice, thats all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9ebdc/1

you can start from finding `MAX`:

```
SELECT 
 MAX(id) max_id
FROM msg
GROUP BY user_id;
```

and then use it as filter:

```
SELECT *
FROM msg
WHERE id IN (
SELECT 
 max(id) max_id
FROM msg
GROUP BY user_id);
```